# AJAX post php response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So i have this code that posts to a php file,

```
var values = {
    'socketid': data.socketid,
    'id': memberid.value
};
console.log(values);
$.ajax({
    url: "continue.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: values,
});
```

but i am unsure how to get each seperate value from the php file continue.php, do i ruse `$_REQUEST` or something, im just not sure if i have to parse or anything, could i get an example on how i can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using POST method just:

```
$socketid = $_POST['socketid'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

`$_REQUEST` is to check both `$_GET` and `$_POST` at the same time but it is not necessay in your code

Comment: you are welcome If the answer is ok please mark it as solved for further reference

Comment: @Bradm please this of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

$_POST should work fine since your request is of type POST

Answer (score 0):

Your continue.php will get values in the following way:

```
<?php
$socket_id=$_POST['socketid'];
id=$_POST['id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple post use `$.post()` it's a shorthand for `$.ajax()` for `POST` request.

```
var values = {
        'socketid': data.socketid,
        'id': memberid.value
    };
    $.post('continue.php', values, function (response) {
        var res = JSON.parse(response);
        if (res.results == true) {
            console.log('Data updated');
        }else {
            console.log('Data not updated');
        }
    })
```

In your `PHP`

```
<?php

$socket_id = $_POST['socketid'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

// here update your data/ use
// then send response to javascript
// echo json_encode(['results' => true]); for success
// echo json_encode(['results' => true]); for fail
```